# LDAP - filter records with two attributes equal (or different)

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I want to filter LDAP records to find entries with two attributes equal (also different).

Let us assume we have records with userid.

> userid=10
>
> userid=15

Each record have name and surname and I want to filter people with identical name and surname.

I can filter people with a particular name using following filter

```
(&(name=Mark)(surname=Mark))
```

But this filter is not correct

```
(=(name)(surname))
```

nor this

```
name=surname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in LDAP. LDAP does not support relational queries even on the attribute level of the same entry.

See [LDAP Query Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).